# Trigger word detection model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I want to create custom wake up word detection model.Is there any opensource RNN wake word detection model for transfer learning.I dont want to use snowboy or anyother. Please do the need

Comment: please be more specific - what is the problem and what did you try so far? SO is not a recommendtion nor a programming service.

Comment: I want a pretrained model for hot word(wake word) detection.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.